# How to render react component onClick?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to render my PostOnWall component I made using an onClick function. The goal that every time someone clicks the button handleClick will render one new component on the screen each time. So if I click the button three times i should see three PostOnWall components rendered on my screen. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
class Textbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClick.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        textArea: "",
        text: "",
        show: false,
        curTime : new Date().toLocaleString(),

      };
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      const myValue = event.target.value;
      this.setState({
        textArea: myValue
      })
      console.log(this.state)
    }

    handleClick= () => {
      this.setState({text:this.state.textArea,
      show: !this.state.show});
      return (
      <div>
          {this.state.show &&   <PostOnWall PostOnWall={this.props.PostOnWall} text={this.state.text} time={this.state.curTime}/>}
        </div>
        );
    }


    showNewPost

      render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <textarea className="Textbox" 
            rows="2" cols="30"
             type = "text" 
             onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
             value={this.state.textArea} >
            </textarea>
              <button className="postbutton" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Post</button>
        </div>

        );
    }
  }



export default Textbox;
```

Comment: Returning the component from the `onClick` handler will do nothing. You need to add the `PostOnWall` component in the render method. You could create an array in local state and every time you click the button you add a component to that state, then in the render method render that array of components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add state which increase on click and then render the component depending on how many time the button is clicked. here the [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cloud-dobje) for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick for you;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Textbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      textArea: '',
      text: '',
      show: false,
      curTime: new Date().toLocaleString(),

    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const myValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      textArea: myValue
    });
  }

  handleClick= () => {
    this.setState({
      text: this.state.textArea,
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          className="Textbox"
          rows="2"
          cols="30"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.textArea}
        />
        <button
          className="postbutton"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          type="button"
        >
          Post
        </button>
        {
          this.state.show &&
            <PostOnWall
              PostOnWall={this.props.PostOnWall}
              text={this.state.text}
              time={this.state.curTime}
            />
        }
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

You should use the function called on click to change the state only. Then render (or not) the PostOnWall component based on the state value.

Comment: Ya that was the first solution I came up with but all it does is hide and show the component. I want render a new PostOnWall componenet every time I click the button

Comment: Then just add an array of posts in the state and use a map in the render just like: { posts.map((post) => (<PostOnWall
              PostOnWall={this.props.PostOnWall}
              text={this.state.text}
              time={this.state.curTime}
            />));